# O que significa Trying to get property non-object

Tags: php, array, orientação-a-objetos

vou explicar o meu problema
Estou trabalhando com uma API e nesta api estou obtendo um determinado campos(codigo,ncm,gtin,origem,codigo_pelo_fornecedor) para isso minha ideia foi usar um `foreach`
desta forma

```
foreach ($content->retorno as $produto){
            echo "SKU: ".$produto->codigo . "<br/>";  
            echo "NCM: ".$produto->ncm . "<br/>";
            echo "Origem: ".$produto->origem . "<br/>";
            echo "GTIN: ".$produto->gtin . "<br/>";
            echo "COD_Fornecedor: ".$produto->codigo_pelo_fornecedor . "<br/>";
            }
```

com este `foreach` eu até tenho retorno desejado mas também tenho um retorno
do seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Retorno do print_r('$content->retorno'):

````
Objeto stdClass ([status_processamento] => 3 
[status] => OK 
[produto] => Objeto stdClass ([id] => 469945219 
[nome] => Cabo Rca Automotivo Blindado Stetsom 5 Metros Flexível Conectores Alta Pressão Banhados Bronze Injetado PVC 
[ codigo] => 106 [unidade] => pç 
[preco] => 18.43 [preco_promocional] => 0 
[ncm] => 8544.42.00 [origem] => 0 
[gtin] => 7897748729927 [gtin_embalagem] => 7897748729927 
[ localizacao] => [peso_liquido] => 0.1 
[peso_bruto] => 0.1 [estoque_minimo] => 8 [estoque_maximo] => 0 [id_fornecedor] => 469834741 
[codigo_fornecedor] =>121 [codigo_pelo_fornecedor] => RCB5M [unidade_por_caixa] => [preco_custo] => 12,42 
[preco_custo_medio] => 12,29 [situação] => A 
[tipo] => P [classe_ipi] => [valor_ipi_fixo] => 0,0000 
[cod_lista_servicos => [tipo_producao] => T 
[tipo_produto_producao] => [descricao_complementar] =>T [tipo_produto_producao] => [descricao_complementar] =>T 
```
````

Comment: O valor veio nulo ou de outro tipo, diferente do tipo (objeto) esperado.

Comment: poderia nos mostrar um `print_r('$content->retorno');` ?

Comment: Entendo, e vc sabe como consigo verificar isso? ou impedir que chame pois o que eu preciso esta no final.

Comment: Remove o foreach e usa $produto = $content->retorno->produto;

Comment: Muito obrigado Benilson, retirando o foreach deu certo